# Optaplanner ConstraintsStream penalize with negative integer

Tags: optaplanner

In my Optaplanner project with constraints-stream score calculation the user can define the `penaltyScore` of the constraints which could be negative or positive.

Is there a neutral variant of `penalize` (which only accepts nonnegative integer as i understand it) or is it necessary to always have sth. ugly like:

```
if(penaltyScore>0){
  ... penalize(...);
} else{
  ... reward(...);
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. What kind of constraint will both penalize and reward? We recently decided that no one would ever want to do that (clearly we're wrong) and introduced fail-fasts in OptaPlanner for it. If you could explain to use the constraint, it will make us understand this.

Comment: Im on a timetabeling app, where the user should be able to define constraints in a flexible two steps way. First he defines a `MatchingCondition` and second a positive or negative `score` indicating if he wants the MatchingCondition to be met or not. Real world use cases that come to my mind are: teacher A beeing absent on timeslot 1+2 while teacher B beeing only availiable on timeslots 1 + 2. So the user could use same MatchingCondition (teacher planned on timeslots 1 + 2) for both constraints.

Comment: Another soft constraint im thinking of is subject A + B shouldnt be on same day (realistic example) while subject C+D should be on same day (I dont know if this is very realistic that someone wants to define the second one.) Many thanks by the way for the great community support here!

Comment: Thanks for the use case description, you've convinced us. A `@ConstraintWeight` won't help there, as that applies to all instances of that constraint. You need to have the `matchWeight` swing both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're fixing this by allowing negative arguments too for a new method, see and track https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-1864

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix!!! When testing it I ran into an exception which I described at Jira.